# passing value from drop down menu to php

Tags: php, html

i have doing a drop down menu to pass the value into php code section to open another php file but it fail to do so,but it show me error 
(Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in C:\xampp\htdocs\web\course.php on line 7)
**This is my html code** 
 http://codepad.org/LcRuKHZj 
**This is my php code**
http://codepad.org/ZFT8BR0Z
**Here is what I plan to do**
when the btnSubmit have been click, it will assign the drop down menu name to $course in a nested if else statement. If the $course matched with the value from option tag in the html code, it will open another php document

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question

Comment: `$course = $_POST("course");` <- should be square brackets
`if(isset($course = "matrix"))` and you've just set this above - try replacing those 2 lines with `if(isset($_POST['course'])) ... `

Comment: Rangad.....the codes are include inside the link

Answer (score 0):

You can't use if(isset($course = "matrix"))
replace it with

```
if( isset($course) && $course == "matrix" ){
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($course) && $course == "matrix")){
 // Do it something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The output is: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ',' or ')' on line 7`
Line 7: `if(isset($course = "matrix"))`
Isset checks, if a variable is set, not if it's value contains a string. Use `if(isset($course))` to check, if the variable is set and not null. If you want to check wether the variable is another variable, use if without isset:
`if($course == "something")`

Comment: Hi kernelmaster, ur explaination very well , my error solved but the page will be display ,the problem is the others php file would pop up when the condition is true

Comment: Use `
 == `
 as operator, not `
 = `
 . My fault, sorry.

Comment: it's ok , u r trying to help me also but unfortunately that one also not working  http://codepad.org/SCF1ExJX refer this link for my code after editing ,is it what u r trying to tell me ?

Comment: the matrix.php file cant be open after I click the submit button, the code after I modify according to ur instruction was stated in the link, because I don know whether I get the wrong instruction or not ?

Comment: http://codepad.org/STMnlNKi  this is my code,hope u can see it coz it's a bt messy,codepad cant paste html code,vry sry ,any way thank for ur help also

Comment: I'm not shure what you want to do. Php is executed when loading the page (Pre Hypertext Processor). The Php code has to be in another file, lets say course.php . You need to define an action for the form using action="mysite.php, in our case mysite.php would be course.php . Then you put the php part that you have in this page to course.php . You dont need a <a> tag in forms, only the submit button.